# what is wrong with this code? when i run this code on browser it not show the effects of jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

its look like this
what is wrong with this code?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HppuZ.png

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Insert page Title </h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Insert content here</p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" >
        <h1>Insert footer here</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed `.js` extension in your `jquery.mobile` script tag

Change,

```
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="b">
      <div data-role="header" >
        <h1>Insert page Title </h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Insert content here</p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" >
        <h1>Insert footer here</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Problem is you have written **jquery.mobile.min** in your script tag where you need to write **jquery.mobile.min.js** in script tag.